# githooks(5): what is the Git "null-ref"

Tags: git, githooks

On the documentation for the [`post-checkout` hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout), it says

> It is also run after [git-clone[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone), unless the `--no-checkout` (`-n`) option is used. The first parameter given to the hook is the null-ref, the second the ref of the new HEAD and the flag is always 1. Likewise for `git worktree add` unless `--no-checkout` is used.

What does the "null-ref" refer to here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the commit ID consisting of all zeros.

I added the following line to `~/.config/git/template/hooks/post-checkout`:

```
echo "post-checkout" "$@" 1>&2
```

and then cloned a new repository, getting the following output:

```
post-checkout 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 4abcac4ddfb69f6dfde1af0164f2f0ee0e230336 1
```

So it looks like the "null-ref" in the `post-checkout` script is `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.

The context behind this question is that I want to set a special per-repo Git config `user.email` value only when I clone repositories from my work's Gitlab server. Now I can put the following in the post-checkout script to change it:

```
# This value of `$1` is the null-ref from githooks(5) - see
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/73000183/207384.
# for sed trick see torek's answer
if [[ "$1" = "$(git rev-parse HEAD | sed s/./0/g)" ]]; then
    # Set user.email specially for work repositories.
    if [[ "$(git config remote."$(git config branch."$(git branch --show-current)".remote)".url)" =~ "gitlab.example.com" ]]; then
        git config user.name "John Doe"
        git config user.email "John Doe@example.com"
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

This documentation probably ought to be updated a bit as the word `null-ref` is misleading, but you're correct that it is an all-zeros hash ID.  Git uses the phrase "null oid" elsewhere, especially internally with a function `is_null_oid`.  Since "OID" is an acronym it's usually upper-cased in English text, and "null" sometimes comes along for the ride: see, e.g., [the 2.18 Release Notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9dd64cb4d310986dd7b8ca7fff92f9b61e0bd21a/Documentation/RelNotes/2.18.0.txt#L472), vs [the `git cat-file` documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9dd64cb4d310986dd7b8ca7fff92f9b61e0bd21a/Documentation/git-cat-file.txt#L261) where it's spelled "null OID".

I personally think `git rev-parse` should have an option for spitting this out (along with the hash ID of the [empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452)), since SHA-256 OIDs are 64 bytes long instead of 40 bytes long.  However, as a stopgap measure, one can use:

```
null_oid=$(git rev-parse HEAD | sed s/./0/g)
```

or, taking the `hash-object` trick a bit further:

```
empty_tree=$(git hash-object -t tree --stdin </dev/null)
null_oid=$(echo $empty_tree | sed s/./0/g)
```

which gets you both and will continue to work in some future Git that has longer OIDs.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says, for the normal `git checkout` case that the first two parameters are

> The hook is given three parameters: the ref of the previous HEAD, the
> ref of the new HEAD (which may or may not have changed), ..."

But in a `git clone` case, obviously, *there is no previous ref*. So some sort of a "null" parameter must be given. In git, the "null ref" of all zeros is provided.